# Using gsub to replace a particular character with a newline (Ruby, Rails console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, newline, gsub

Annoying problem. I am trying to replace all semicolon characters in my Model's description field with newline characters (\n). The database is sqlite. The field is of type text.

If I do it manually at the rails console (manually typing the description for a single record using \n for line breaks), the rails console automatically escapes the \n, and the description field becomes filled with `\\n`.

If I do it programmatically using gsub, I get the following situation:

```
>> s = Sample.find(:first)
```

=> ...details of record ...

```
>> s.description.gsub!(/;/,"\n")
```

=> ...success - it all looks good, new lines in the returned value are represented by \n...

```
>> s.save

=> true

>> reload!

Reloading

=> true

>> s = Sample.find(:first)
```

=> ...details of record ...

```
>> s.description
```

=> ... the description field still has semicolons in it rather than newline characters ...

AHHHHHH!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure you're always getting the same sample back? What do the logs say?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`s.description` returns a copy of the description so `gsub!` will only modify the copy and return the modified copy.

Try this:

```
s.description = s.description.gsub(/;/,"\n")
```

Comment: He's using gsub! which will modify-in-place description and save it.

Comment: That's what I thought too, Radar. However Vincent's solution seems to work. Using the destructive variant of gsub wasn't working for me. The field was unmodified after performing a save. I was working in the rails console if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing ActiveRecord fields a lot, you can just edit them in your editor with the rails plugin [console_update](http://github.com/cldwalker/console_update#readme)